# How to synchronize these threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

In this program, I'm creating 4 threads and each of them is printing 1/4 of an array. But i want them to be synchronized. When i make the method run() `synchronized`, the threads are still printing their part of the array randomly:

```
Thread 1:0
Thread 3:50
Thread 3:51
Thread 3:52
Thread 3:53
Thread 3:54
Thread 2:25
Thread 3:55
Thread 3:56
Thread 3:57
Thread 1:1
Thread 3:58
Thread 4:75
Thread 4:76
Thread 4:77
Thread 4:78
Thread 4:79
Thread 4:80
Thread 2:26
```

---

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         final int M = 100;
         final int N = 4;
         final int[] array = new int[M];

         for(int b = 0; b < M; b++) array[b] = b;

         for( int p = 0; p < N; p++) {
             final int i = p;
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public synchronized void run() {
                         for(int a = i*(M/N);a < (i+1)*(M/N); a++)
                             System.out.println("Thread "+(i+1)+":"+array[a]); 
                     }
             }).start();
         }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that you want them "synchronized"? What output are you hoping for? If you want the results in order, then consider not using separate threads.

Comment: Consider what you are synchronizing **on**.

Comment: I think you mean `serialized` and if you want that then don't use threads. Voting to close because this isn't clear at all.

Comment: I want the to print their part of the array in order.

Comment: Given the output is exactly the sample as a simple loop in one thread, can you add why you are trying to do this at all?

Comment: My target is to create four threads,and each one of them to print 1/4 of the given array in ORDER (  first thread is printing it`s part, the second thread, the third and the fourth... not mixed printing). Is that possible ?

Comment: As I mentioned in the first comment to your question, and as @PeterLawrey reiterates, if you want the data printed in order, it would be best not to use separate threads. It somewhat negates one of the reasons to use threading. The other negation is that you will likely get no real benefit timewise by using threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the question is not clear at all, I guess that you may want to print each sub-array with the correct order.

This means an output like this one:

```
Thread 1:0
Thread 1:1
Thread 1:2
Thread 1:3
Thread 1:4
Thread 1:5
Thread 1:6
Thread 1:7
Thread 1:8
Thread 1:9
Thread 1:10
Thread 1:11
Thread 1:12
Thread 1:13
Thread 1:14
Thread 1:15
Thread 1:16
Thread 1:17
Thread 1:18
Thread 1:19
Thread 1:20
Thread 1:21
Thread 1:22
Thread 1:23
Thread 1:24
Thread 4:75
Thread 4:76
Thread 4:77
Thread 4:78
Thread 4:79
Thread 4:80
Thread 4:81
Thread 4:82
Thread 4:83
Thread 4:84
Thread 4:85
Thread 4:86
Thread 4:87
Thread 4:88
Thread 4:89
Thread 4:90
Thread 4:91
Thread 4:92
Thread 4:93
Thread 4:94
Thread 4:95
Thread 4:96
Thread 4:97
Thread 4:98
Thread 4:99
Thread 3:50
Thread 3:51
Thread 3:52
Thread 3:53
Thread 3:54
Thread 3:55
Thread 3:56
Thread 3:57
Thread 3:58
Thread 3:59
Thread 3:60
Thread 3:61
Thread 3:62
Thread 3:63
Thread 3:64
Thread 3:65
Thread 3:66
Thread 3:67
Thread 3:68
Thread 3:69
Thread 3:70
Thread 3:71
Thread 3:72
Thread 3:73
Thread 3:74
Thread 2:25
Thread 2:26
Thread 2:27
Thread 2:28
Thread 2:29
Thread 2:30
Thread 2:31
Thread 2:32
Thread 2:33
Thread 2:34
Thread 2:35
Thread 2:36
Thread 2:37
Thread 2:38
Thread 2:39
Thread 2:40
Thread 2:41
Thread 2:42
Thread 2:43
Thread 2:44
Thread 2:45
Thread 2:46
Thread 2:47
Thread 2:48
Thread 2:49
```

To do this, you just have to add an `Object` to *synchronize* to, and you can use something like this:

```
final Object lock = new Object();
```

Then you need to change you `run` method to synchronize on `lock`

```
public void run() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        for (int a = i * (M / N); a < (i + 1) * (M / N); a++) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + (i + 1) + ":" + array[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the full edited main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int M = 100;
    final int N = 4;
    final int[] array = new int[M];
    final Object lock = new Object(); // LOCK!!

    for (int b = 0; b < M; b++) {
        array[b] = b;
    }

    for (int p = 0; p < N; p++) {
        final int i = p;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (lock) { // SYNCHRONIZED BLOCK INSTEAD OF SYNCHRONIZED METHOD
                    for (int a = i * (M / N); a < (i + 1) * (M / N); a++) {
                        System.out.println("Thread " + (i + 1) + ":" + array[a]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Of course, if you just want to print your array following the same order of the elements inside, you don't have to deal with threads.

EDIT:

A little explanation of why your code doesn't work as you expected:

A *synchronized* method can be seen as a method which is synchronized on itself.

This means that

```
synchronized void method(){
    doSomething();
}
```

can be seen as

```
void method(){
    synchronized(this){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Getting to your code, you have 4 different instances of `Runnable` with a `synchronized void run()` method.

This means that each `run` will synchronize on a different object (the `Runnable` instance) and that's why there's no synchronization at all.

To "work together", the threads must synchronize on the same object!

Comment: This doesn't guarantee proper ordering between threads. The threads will be allowed to acquire the lock in any order.

Comment: But once a thread acquires the lock, it prints everything before releasing it and that's what the OP asked for. Having the proper ordering between thread would just mean writing `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`

Comment: synchronized(this) can lead to deadlock,but isn`t synchronized(lock) in your example the same ?

Comment: Yes, maybe OP really just wants the subarrays to print contiguously. I don't see much sense in such a requirement, but that's another story :)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a sample code. @Marko Topolnik: yeah, I don't see much sense too but we're here to just answer without thinking too much :D

Comment: This is an entirely long yet very wrong explanation. synchronizing this cannot cause a deadlock, only wrong coding can do that. And in this case it doesn't matter on what you synchronize, bad code is bad code. Your example only looks deadlocked because you have a while(true) statement. What you don't do is synchronizing on non-final variables, but you do that, even allow a setter.
In addition you fail to mention how stupid it is to synchronize the whole run method of a Thread.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to print an array in order is to use one thread.  You can change your code you use `run()` instead of `start()`  Or you could have one thread doing the printing and the other threads do nothing.

This is because thread are design to work best when they have independent tasks they can perform concurrently.  When you have tasks which must occur in a specific order, use one thread.

BTW Your synchronized isn't doing anything useful as each thread is locking a different object.  You need to lock the same object in each thread to share a resource (This won't fix you problem but it will at least be thread safe)  The obvious choice is to synchronize on the `array` object

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you are using Threads in a wrong way. By definition the order of execution of Threads is **undefined**, therefore the order they print on a console is equally undefined. If you use threads, you must have a task where the order of execution (read results) is not important (like not important or sorted later) or you cannot use threads.

If you now want to synchronize threads in a way that they are in order, that means that if you have 4 threads 3/4 of all threads are constantly blocked, or in other words: 3/4 of the time on a thread is spent on waiting and only 1/4 on actually working. 1/4 * 4 = 1, so you effectively have the execution speed of a single-threaded application minus the overhead for thread synchronization.

In addition: synchronizing the run method of a thread means you effectively disable threading, because at any given time only one thread is able to actually work.

Nevertheless I found the question intriguing enough to give it a thought and came up with the following (dirty) code that fulfills your requirement using a [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) for synchronization. Here is the final code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Test {

  private static volatile int lastNumber = -1;

  private static void printNumber(int number) {
    if (number != lastNumber + 1) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Tried to print numbers out of order!");
    } else {
      if (number % 20 == 19) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%3d, ", number));
      } else {
        System.out.print(String.format("%3d, ", number));
      }
      lastNumber = number;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final int MAX_NUMBER = 1000;
    final int NUM_THREADS = 4;

    final AtomicInteger number = new AtomicInteger(0);
    final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(NUM_THREADS);

    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
      executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
            int numberPicked;
            while ((numberPicked = number.getAndIncrement()) < MAX_NUMBER) {
              while (phaser.getPhase() != numberPicked) {
                phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
              }
              printNumber(numberPicked);
              phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            }
          } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
          } finally {
            phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
          }
        }
      });
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

This works, because all threads constantly synchronize using the phaser and only print if it is their turn. They literally pick a number and then sit down and wait till their number is called. Effectively that causes the threads to print in order as requested.

Please note that the `printNumber` function is not only for convenience but to verify that the order is correct as well. It does not order the numbers in any way, but it will throw an exception if the number to print is not lastNumber + 1. And this is only working fine, because the code ensures that only one thread at any time calls this function. Printing the array value should be done in this function for your code instead of what I am printing.

Measuring the execution time confirms that all threads spent about 60% of their time waiting, so we get a speed increase of ~20% compared to a single-threaded execution, which is spent almost entirely on `String.format`. So this is a very bad gain at a much more complex code.